# Do creatures spawn at rails?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Can any creature(pig, bat, creeper,...) spawn directly on the top of either simple iron rails or powered ones? If not, what is the distance between rails and a creature?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, mobs cannot spawn on rails. I did a little test in a Superflat world to see if they could, but they didn't. As soon as I removed some rails the mobs started spawning in the empty spot. The same applied to powered rails (both powered and unpowered)
[image: Superflat world with rails]